# How to check invoice is shipped or not in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice

Hi guys can we check order **invoice** is shipped or not like if order has 3 invoices i want to get only that invoice that is not shipped yet. I have order **invoice collection** and order **shipment collection** how can i check which invoice is shipped and which is not here is the code of both collection

> Shipment collection

```
    array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(15) {
    ["entity_id"]=>
    string(2) "14"
    ["store_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["total_weight"]=>
    NULL
    ["total_qty"]=>
    string(6) "2.0000"
    ["email_sent"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["order_id"]=>
    string(2) "40"
    ["customer_id"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["shipping_address_id"]=>
    string(2) "80"
    ["billing_address_id"]=>
    string(2) "79"
    ["shipment_status"]=>
    NULL
    ["increment_id"]=>
    string(9) "100000032"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-09-26 06:45:46"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-09-26 06:45:51"
    ["packages"]=>
    NULL
    ["shipping_label"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

> Invoice Collection

```
    array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(63) {
    ["entity_id"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["store_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["base_grand_total"]=>
    string(8) "387.7000"
    ["shipping_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["tax_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["base_tax_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["store_to_order_rate"]=>
    string(6) "1.0000"
    ["base_shipping_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["base_discount_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["base_to_order_rate"]=>
    string(6) "1.0000"
    ["grand_total"]=>
    string(8) "387.7000"
    ["shipping_amount"]=>
    string(6) "5.7000"
    ["subtotal_incl_tax"]=>
    string(8) "382.0000"
    ["base_subtotal_incl_tax"]=>
    string(8) "382.0000"
    ["store_to_base_rate"]=>
    string(6) "1.0000"
    ["base_shipping_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["total_qty"]=>
    string(6) "4.0000"
    ["base_to_global_rate"]=>
    string(6) "1.0000"
    ["subtotal"]=>
    string(8) "382.0000"
    ["base_subtotal"]=>
    string(8) "382.0000"
    ["discount_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["billing_address_id"]=>
    string(2) "79"
    ["is_used_for_refund"]=>
    NULL
    ["order_id"]=>
    string(2) "40"
    ["email_sent"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["can_void_flag"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["state"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["shipping_address_id"]=>
    string(2) "80"
    ["store_currency_code"]=>
    string(3) "BHD"
    ["transaction_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["order_currency_code"]=>
    string(3) "BHD"
    ["base_currency_code"]=>
    string(3) "BHD"
    ["global_currency_code"]=>
    string(3) "BHD"
    ["increment_id"]=>
    string(9) "100000044"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-09-25 14:07:57"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-09-25 14:07:57"
    ["hidden_tax_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["base_hidden_tax_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["shipping_hidden_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt"]=>
    NULL
    ["shipping_incl_tax"]=>
    NULL
    ["base_shipping_incl_tax"]=>
    NULL
    ["base_total_refunded"]=>
    NULL
    ["discount_description"]=>
    NULL
    ["base_customer_balance_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["customer_balance_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["base_gift_cards_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["gift_cards_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["gw_base_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_items_base_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_items_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_card_base_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_card_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_base_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_items_base_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_items_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_card_base_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_card_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["base_reward_currency_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["reward_currency_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["reward_points_balance"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(63) {
    ["entity_id"]=>
    string(2) "21"
    ["store_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["base_grand_total"]=>
    string(8) "387.7000"
    ["shipping_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["tax_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["base_tax_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["store_to_order_rate"]=>
    string(6) "1.0000"
    ["base_shipping_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["base_discount_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["base_to_order_rate"]=>
    string(6) "1.0000"
    ["grand_total"]=>
    string(8) "387.7000"
    ["shipping_amount"]=>
    string(6) "5.7000"
    ["subtotal_incl_tax"]=>
    string(8) "382.0000"
    ["base_subtotal_incl_tax"]=>
    string(8) "382.0000"
    ["store_to_base_rate"]=>
    string(6) "1.0000"
    ["base_shipping_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["total_qty"]=>
    string(6) "3.0000"
    ["base_to_global_rate"]=>
    string(6) "1.0000"
    ["subtotal"]=>
    string(8) "382.0000"
    ["base_subtotal"]=>
    string(8) "382.0000"
    ["discount_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["billing_address_id"]=>
    string(2) "79"
    ["is_used_for_refund"]=>
    NULL
    ["order_id"]=>
    string(2) "40"
    ["email_sent"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["can_void_flag"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["state"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["shipping_address_id"]=>
    string(2) "80"
    ["store_currency_code"]=>
    string(3) "BHD"
    ["transaction_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["order_currency_code"]=>
    string(3) "BHD"
    ["base_currency_code"]=>
    string(3) "BHD"
    ["global_currency_code"]=>
    string(3) "BHD"
    ["increment_id"]=>
    string(9) "100000045"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-09-26 07:10:26"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-09-26 07:10:26"
    ["hidden_tax_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["base_hidden_tax_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["shipping_hidden_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt"]=>
    NULL
    ["shipping_incl_tax"]=>
    NULL
    ["base_shipping_incl_tax"]=>
    NULL
    ["base_total_refunded"]=>
    NULL
    ["discount_description"]=>
    NULL
    ["base_customer_balance_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["customer_balance_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["base_gift_cards_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["gift_cards_amount"]=>
    string(6) "0.0000"
    ["gw_base_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_items_base_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_items_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_card_base_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_card_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_base_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_items_base_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_items_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_card_base_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["gw_card_tax_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["base_reward_currency_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["reward_currency_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["reward_points_balance"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Invoice is not related to shipment, but you can easily relate invoice item to shipped order item
With a query like :

```
select sfoi.* from sales_flat_order_item sfoi left join sales_flat_invoice_item sfii on sfii.parent_id = sfoi.item_id
where sfoi.qty_shipped > 0;
```